# JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data on sending Javascript

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a simple message box, using "remote: true", and then replacing a flash_message div with a success or failure message. For some reason this keeps on giving the error "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data".

My view:

```
= form_for Message.new, remote: true, format: :js do |f|
  = hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token
  = f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Naam'
  = f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'E-mail'
  = f.text_area :message, placeholder: 'Jouw bericht'
  = f.submit

#flash-message
```

My controller:

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @message.valid?
      # MessageMailer.contact(@message).deliver

      format.html
      format.js { flash.now[:success] = "Thank you for your message. I'll get back to you soon!" }
    else
      format.html
      format.js { flash.now[:failure] = "Something went wrong!" }
    end
  end
end
```

My create.js.erb:

```
$('#flash-message').html("<%= j render 'flash' %>").delay(3000).fadeOut(4000);
```

On the terminal I see:

```
Started POST "/messages.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-10 16:14:33 +0200
Processing by MessagesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/3VXW31YVYF/mfle+JiHHx1jRguLF4TkepPWGqXYhP4tc/qS2IfGWlWpvcW4A4pwwcTGmHZJHnpzajqT+ETLiw==", "message"=>{"name"=>"", "email"=>"", "message"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Message"}
  Rendering messages/create.js.erb
  Rendered messages/_flash.html.slim (2.3ms)
  Rendered messages/create.js.erb (3.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 11.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And in the browser I get

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

$('#flash-message').html("<div class=\"alert alert-failure\">Something went wrong!<\/div>").delay(3000).fadeOut(4000);
```

I'm apparently doing something very wrong, but don't understand why my javascript code suddenly gets parsed as json.

I've been googling the error, but to no avail.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you think of including the problematic JSON string in your question?

Comment: @marekful - as far as I know I'm not using any JSON at all. Purpose is to just deliver some Javascript (see the second line in the browser feedback above), but that code is somehow interpreted as JSON...? And even if I replace that code by a simple javascript popup, I still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

As they say - never to old to learn... 10 minutes after posting this question, and after 3 hours of trying to find the cause of the problem, I suddenly saw I didn't include jquery_ujs into my application.js file, causing apparently all the above trouble.

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Hope this question helps someone in the future!